# Module not found : Error : Can't resolve 'istanbul-instrumenter-loader' while executing the tests

Tags: typescript, karma-jasmine

I am new to Angular 2 testings and I working hard to write the tests referring angular io documentation. 
While I was working on a sample spec, I am getting the error :
"Module not found : Error : Can't resolve 'istanbul-instrumenter-loader' ".

Could anyone please direct me to resolve this issue and help in proceeding further.

Thanks in advance.
Thank you,
Vivek

Comment: It looks like you haven't installed this npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/istanbul-instrumenter-loader

Comment: Even after installing I am facing the same issue.

Comment: maybe you're installing the right version of the package & you should downgrade it a bit